# Automating <a href=""> Links (EPUB, HTML)

Tags: epub, editing, html, creation

**EDIT: Disregard this question**, I solved it using regular expressions (I thought they wouldn't work in this scenario but they did)

I'm working on a translation of a text which is divided into short, numbered sections. It looks something like this:

51. Following his departure from Athens, the general decided to [...]
52. It was around this same time that the Egyptian king was assassinated, and the realm was thrown into chaos.

Now, these numbered sections are contained within their own `<p>` tags, so these numbers are directly preceded by a `<p>`, like so:

```
<p>55. Following the events of the Spring[...]</p>
```

I have a completed epub, comprised of 8 html files, each file containing roughly 150 sections numbered 1 through 150 and beginning again at number 1 in the next html file. The ebook itself is separated into chapters one through eight, corresponding with the numbers of the html files.

Now here's the catch: **I have another translation. I would like to include this alternative translation in the same ebook, with the numbered sections containing a hyperlink to the alternative translation.** This would be done by containing the numbers inside `<a href="">` tags which also link to the corresponding number in the alternative translation, like so:

Current:

```
<p>68. The king liked cats.</p>
```

Desired:

```
<p><a href="[ALTERNATIVE LINK TO SECTION 68]">68.</a> The king liked cats.</p>
```

But after clicking the "68." link to read translation #2, it would be nice to have a link which circles back to translation #1, which will be contained in the second translation's "68."

So, effectively, I already have the necessary markers to designate the place and the contents of the `<a href=>` tags, the only thing that I lack is a way to automate this process, since I have well over 1,000 numbered sections to link back and forth to each other. I'm a noob when it comes to ebooks so I'm not even sure if it's possible, I mainly mess around with Calibre and it seems like such a thing may be possible using the Python functions, but I have no idea where to start.

Comment: It would be nice to describe your solution in an answer. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question, so others can learn from your experience.